# Android video view not showing button on it's top in a custom dialog box

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-videoview

friends, I have an issue in Android, I want to show a video view in a custom dialogue in Android and also want to show a close button on the top of the video view. the problem is that the video is showing behind the dialogue so the video appears in darker, when I set the dim effect zero I lost the beauty of the dialogue so I try another method I set the video view on top of the dialogue but in this case I can't place the button on top of video view. my problem is that I want the dim effect of dialogue and also place the close button in the top of video view, anybody please help me.

This is my xml code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="500dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:background="@drawable/curve_shape">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button_close"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/window_close_button_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/window_close_button_height"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_windowclose"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_close" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/progress_bar_big"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_bar_big"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button_close" />
```

this is the code of my video view

```
    Uri video = Uri.parse(response.body().getVideo());
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mVideoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
```

Comment: Post your xml file

Comment: okay, please check. I added the code.

Comment: It appears fine, is there any specific reason you have set your parent layout width to `500dp`?  also if you are testing in earlier version you need to add `layout_constraintRight_toRightOf`

Comment: it appears fine because now the video view is set to the bottom of the button. I want to set the button above the video view.and the setZorderOnTop true for video view it hides the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a small hack that might work for you, try adding a little bit of elevation to your view.

```
android:elevation="5dp" //or anything of your choice
```

This might bring your view on top of the video.